# Accept DTMF in ongoing Conference Using Confbridge

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I am Using confbridge and I want to accept/read DTMF from user in ongoing conference

I had tried dtmf_passthrough but it is not working,

We are Using Asterisk 13.13.0 and My confbridge.conf configuration is given below

```
[default_user]
type = user
admin = no
;pin = 1111
marked = yes
startmuted = yes
announce_user_count = yes
announce_user_count_all = 1
announce_join_leave = yes
dtmf_passthrough=yes


[user_menu]
type = menu
1 = toggle_mute
201 = leave_conference


[default_bridge]
type = bridge

[admin_user]
type=user
;pin=5555
admin=yes   
marked=no  
music_on_hold_when_empty=yes  ; 
dtmf_passthrough=yes
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: it should work. how do you read dtmf and what version of asterisk you are using?

Comment: Thanks you for your reply, I have updated my question for more information Please check

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion.

1. Make sure DTMF is working on your device.
2. Make sure you have included your menu option in your dialplan command. Like this
   `exten => 111,1,ConfBridge(my_test_bridge,default_bridge,default_user,user_menu)`
3. set dtmf_passthrough=no